# See which posts user has viewed

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a table user it has:

```
id INT PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
```

Also I have table post

```
id INT PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT
post TEXT NOT NULL
```

If user visits a certain post I would like to store somewhere in the database that he has already viewed the said post. How would I go about modifying the database to accommodate for that and how would I query for the posts that user has not seen. Should I create a new table to store that info? Or is there some other nifty trick?
The idea is that I simply want a way where if user views the post once he can not view it ever again.
Sorry I am just trying to learn databases and this is one challenge I find quite interesting and difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to implement a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29): a User visits multiple Posts, and a Post is visited by multiple users.

This will take the form of a table with only two columns, each of them being a foreign key to one of your existing tables:

```
CREATE TABLE user_post_visit (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    post_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, post_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_id) REFERENCES post(id)
);
```

Add a record into this table every time a user views a post. In order to find posts that a given user has **not** viewed yet:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post
LEFT JOIN user_post_visit AS upv
    ON (upv.post_id = post.id AND upv.user_id = <your user ID here>)
WHERE upv.post_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: That simple O_o I am simply stunned, this has not occurred to me at all, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I follow behind @RandomSeed. :D

It seems to me that you want many-to-many relation so you need a new table. How you do it is not strict but for example

Table "read_post" or "unread_post":

> user_id, post_id

If the table is unread_post (but you have to create new row to every user when new post created) you can show unread post:

> SELECT text FROM post INNER JOIN unread_post ON post.id =
>   unread_post.post_id WHERE user_id = ?

If table is read_post get unread see RandomSeeds answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use what RandomSeed has suggested for creating a bridge-table between user and post and then use the following to query out the posts viewed by a user:

```
SELECT post_id, post FROM user_post_visit, post WHERE user_post_visit.user_id=<user id>
```