# Is there a way to implement this left join table using sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

**Some Background**

I create a simple database with 3 tables. A post table, a user table, and a junction table user_post_visits. The goal of the 3rd table is to track which posts a user has already seen.
I followed this post for the idea of the third table. [See which posts user has viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534956/see-which-posts-user-has-viewed).

**Associations**

Here are how the tables are currently associated

```
Post.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: "User_Post_Visit" });
User.belongsToMany(models.Post, { through: "User_Post_Visit" });
```

**Issue**

I don't understand how to query for the unseen posts using the query methods sequelized has. I did some research and found an example for finding these posts using sql. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18535049/7355364.

Using my tables the query would be.

```
SELECT Posts.* FROM Posts LEFT JOIN User_Post_Visits AS upv ON (upv.postid = Posts.id AND upv.userId = ${user_id}) WHERE upv.postId IS NULL;
```

**How create this query using the Sequelize API?** *I am free/open to alter tables as needed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
const { literal } = require('sequelize');

const { Post } = require('./data/models');

const product = await Post.findAll({
    include: [{ model: models.User_Post_Visit, as: 'upv', where: { userId } }],
    where: { '$"upv"."postId"$': null }
});
```

Comment: I had to make a few small changes, but it works! I can see where it looks for the user. How could I add that into the literal? After that this is the answer to my question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should try this. I changed my answer.

Comment: I actually tried your new literal, and it did not work for me. What did work was using the query method, passing in the sql query in the second link I shared. But I want to use the Sequelize API. The correct answer would be remaking this query or something similar using the Sequelize API.  `SELECT Posts.* FROM Posts LEFT JOIN User_Post_Visits AS upv ON (upv.postid = Posts.id AND upv.userId = ${user_id}) WHERE upv.postId IS NULL;`

Comment: I edited my question to match what I just commented

Comment: I have edited my answer, I think it will help you.